# Flutter block pattern simplified

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm pretty new to flutter and I got to know about flutter block pattern in some sources but non of them didn't give me a proper explanation about this block pattern. I'd highly appreciate that if someone can explain it to me with an example. thank you so much

What I tried to accomplish is convert my flutter app with firebase database according to flutter block pattern.

Comment: I would suggest to read this article https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1. If it's not clear for you afterwards, just create a test app and ask speciffic question based on the app issues that you might have.

Comment: I'm working on that sir thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official website:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

You can find BLoC pattern related sources down below, also other state management sources as well.

First understand the concept of BLoC, then look for examples on GitHub/search feature.

This one is most beginner friendly BLoC article I can say:

https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

Comment: Stephen Grider has beginner friendly examples:
https://github.com/StephenGrider/FlutterCasts/tree/master/login_bloc
https://github.com/StephenGrider/FlutterCasts/tree/master/news

Answer (score 1):

Check Simple Counter Example with bloc pattern:

[How to handle state in Flutter using the BLoc pattern]

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-handle-state-in-flutter-using-the-bloc-pattern-8ed2f1e49a13